# How do I serve static files from an nginx map?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have an nginx [map](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule) inside a configuration that looks like this:

```
map $uri $route {
  /route_a /path/to/a.html;
  /route_b /path/to/b.html;
}

server {    
  listen 8080;
  server_name example.dev;
}
```

I tried `rewrite` inside the server block:

```
rewrite  ^ $route break;
```

But got a 404 when trying to access `/route_a`.

I tried `location` and `alias` inside the server block:

```
location ~ ^ {
  alias $route;
}
```

Which worked, but served my content as `application/octet-stream`.

What's the correct way to do this?

My constraint is that the URI paths-to-files must be defined inside the `map` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your error log to see what actually happens. This configuration works for me:

```
map $uri $route {
    /route_a /path/to/a.html;
    /route_b /path/to/b.html;
}

server {
    root /;
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ $route break;
    }
}
```

Of course, /path/to/[ab].html must exists.

Maybe you just forget to set right path using "root" directive?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize the `root` directive was required.